# How do I pass the activeadmin query string to a batch_action?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am building an admin UI using ActiveAdmin.

- Ruby v2.0
- Rails 4.0.13
- ActiveAdmin 1.0.0pre

I am creating a batch_action which takes the list of filtered IDs and stores them as a segment. Along with a name for the segment I want to store the activeadmin query string that created the segment.

The query string for current page does not appear to get passed in with the batch_action post so it seems I will have to add some Javascript to grab it and pass it along.

I was wondering if there was a solution I am overlooking or if anyone else has solved this problem?

Comment: Here is the solution I came up with this afternoon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with this afternoon.

I added the file /assets/javascripts/active_admin/query_string.js which contains the code to pull the query string out of the current page.

I am decoding it but that is only necessary depending on what you want to do with it:

```
(function (w, d, $, undefined) {
  'use strict';

  var admin_query_string = function() {
    var href = window.location.href,
      tokens = href.split('?'),
      qs = '';

    if (tokens.length > 1) {
      qs = decodeURIComponent(tokens[1]);
    }

    return qs;
  };

  w.admin_query_string = admin_query_string;
}(window, document, jQuery));
```

Then I added the file /assets/javascripts/active_admin/testers.js. Tester is a model in our application.

The active_admin Tester resource has a batch_action :create_segment which takes a :name, :query, and list of :ids and creates a segment of testers.

The javascript only run if the current page is the active_admin testers page:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  $(function() {
    if ($('body.admin_testers').length) {
      $("a.batch_action[data-action='create_segment']").on('click', function() {
        $("input[name='query']").val(mycrowd_admin_query_string());
      });
    }
  });
}).call(this);
```